# How to use has_many through relation with has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to build a model which uses `has_many :through` with the `has_one` relationship.

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :bills, through: :users # I expect cart has many bills
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :bill
  belongs_to :cart
end

class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :cart
end
```

When I try to call `cart.bills`, it returns the first bill even though it has more bills.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the user model declaration, You have specified that user can only have one bill which is why you are getting only one record.
Correct thing would be :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :bills
 belongs_to :cart
end
```

You can refer to this rails [DOC](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)